# Error loading Yolov5 Model to Local System

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection, yolov5

I am using Yolov5 ultralytics pytorch colab notebook to train over my custom dataset. I saved the model and wanted to use to make predictions over my local PC but encountered an error

> Downloading: "https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/zipball/master" to
> C:\Users\ATI/.cache\torch\hub\master.zip YOLOv5  2023-3-20
> Python-3.9.16 torch-2.0.0+cu117 CPU
>
> Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text
> editor
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) File ~/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py:49,
> in _create(name, pretrained, channels, classes, autoshape, verbose,
> device)
> 48 try:
> ---> 49     model = DetectMultiBackend(path, device=device, fuse=autoshape)  # detection model
> 50     if autoshape:
>
> File
> ~/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\common.py:344, in
> DetectMultiBackend.**init**(self, weights, device, dnn, data, fp16,
> fuse)
> 343 if pt:  # PyTorch
> --> 344     model = attempt_load(weights if isinstance(weights, list) else w, device=device, inplace=True, fuse=fuse)
> 345     stride = max(int(model.stride.max()), 32)  # model stride
>
> File
> ~/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\experimental.py:80,
> in attempt_load(weights, device, inplace, fuse)
> 79 ckpt = torch.load(attempt_download(w), map_location='cpu')  # load
> ---> 80 ckpt = (ckpt.get('ema') or ckpt['model']).to(device).float()  # FP32 model
> 82 # Model compatibility updates
>
> KeyError: 'model'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) File ~/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py:60,
> in _create(name, pretrained, channels, classes, autoshape, verbose,
> device)
> 59     except Exception:
> ---> 60         model = attempt_load(path, device=device, fuse=False)  # arbitrary model ...
> 76 help_url = 'https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/36'
> 77 s = f'{e}. Cache may be out of date, try `force_reload=True` or see {help_url} for help.'
> ---> 78 raise Exception(s) from e
>
> Exception: 'model'. Cache may be out of date, try `force_reload=True`
> or see https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/36 for help

[image: Code]